# How do I plot data on matplotlib, pull in the last 6 months of data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I just want `matplotlib` to plot the last 6 months of data instead of all the data. I have a dataset of all btc historical prices, and I am able to plot all the data for the historical prices. But when I am writing the code, I am running into this problem:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1504         try:
-> 1505             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
```

I did a 6 month price prediction, predictive analysis for eth, and I am trying to do the same for bitcoin.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/Cassady3499/Ethproject/blob/master/Copy_of_Copy_of_Copy_of_python_eth_project.ipynb)

Here is what I have, and what works.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
​
btcpred_df = pd.read_csv('btcpred.csv')
btcpred_df[['date','PriceUSD']].set_index('date').plot();
```

The rest of the code below that (in the link) doesn't work.

I am just expecting to see the last 6 months of my bitcoin data plotted, just like i have in the eth file.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please reformat code blocks of your question. See tips on the right when you in editing mode.

Comment: Hey RAMe0, I reformated the code blocks for my question. Are you able to help me with my problem? Do you understand what I am asking?